# How to properly use ShardedByS3Key in distributed training scenario?

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

Following the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_S3DataSource.html), one way to optimize data ingestion for distributed training is using `ShardedByS3Key`.

Does have code samples for using `ShardedByS3Key` in context of distributed training? Concretely, what changes to, e.g., PT's `DistributedSampler` (should it be used at all?), or TF's `tf.data`-pipeline is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

According to the technique of "[Sharded Data Parallelism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-parallel-extended-features-pytorch-sharded-data-parallelism.html)":

> The standard data parallelism technique replicates the training states
> across the GPUs in the data parallel group, and performs gradient
> aggregation based on the AllReduce operation.

Then simply leave the default mode `FullyReplicated` in your [TrainingInput](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/inputs.html#sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput)'s distribution param because parallelism does not occur at the level of data division on upstream instances but later on gpu.

See the guide on "[How to apply Sharded data parallelism to your training work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-parallel-extended-features-pytorch-sharded-data-parallelism.html#model-parallel-extended-features-pytorch-sharded-data-parallelism-how-to-use)" or the full example notebook "[Train GPT-2 with near-linear scaling using Sharded Data Parallelism technique in SageMaker Model Parallelism Library](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/training/distributed_training/pytorch/model_parallel/gpt2/smp-train-gpt-simple-sharded-data-parallel.ipynb)".
In the last example it sets just the parameters step by step explicitly.

---

For example, you have to set at least the `distribution` dict params on [PyTorch](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html) (or [TensorFlow](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/sagemaker.tensorflow.html)) estimator to enable the SageMaker distributed data parallelism:

```
{ "smdistributed": { "dataparallel": { "enabled": True } } }
```